# Simulink Simscape Motor Blows Up with Torque Feedback

Tags: dc-motor, simulation, matlab, simulink

I am trying to simulate a DC motor using the Simscape -> Electrical -> Specialized Power Systems. I try to simulate an increased inertia by using \$\tau=J\frac{d\omega}{dt}\$ where \$\tau\$ is the torque load on the motor, \$J\$ is moment of inertia and \$\omega\$ is the motor angular speed. The motor speed and current blow up to a very large value if I have the multiplying constant more than 0.022. The model runs fine if I give the motor a constant torque of any value.

The simulation model is shown in the diagram. I tried to use both discrete and continuous derivative but the result is the same. The graphs from the scope and various configurations for the model are in the diagrams. Using continuous simulation has the same effect, except the simulation stops midway with an error saying some derivative is not a real number anymore.

Windows 10 Home

MATLAB R2023a

Is there a mistake I am doing? Is there a better way to do this?

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]